# Query using CodeIgniter's Active Record not returning a value…

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here's the code I'm running.

```
$query = $this->db->query("DECLARE @tmp TABLE (ContactID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
INSERT INTO tblCD (" . ArrayToString($fieldsCDArray) . ")
OUTPUT Inserted.ContactID INTO @tmp
VALUES (" . ArrayToDBString($valuesCDArray) . ")
INSERT INTO tblCCO (ContactID, " . ArrayToString($fieldsCCOArray) . ")
VALUES ((SELECT ContactID FROM @tmp), " . ArrayToDBString($valuesCCOArray) . ")
SELECT ContactID FROM @tmp");

$result = $query->row();
```

I've ran $this->db->last_query() to verify that the SQL code actually works in SQL server. It ends up returning a single row, as expected. But I get nothing returned from CodeIgniter with the above code. I've also tried running it with result() and result_array() just for kicks, and still nothing.

Does CodeIgniter not like returning results from a query with more than one statement in it or do I have to get the result a different way? (For anyone asking, I’m just trying to get the last inserted id but it's a GUID so I can't use $this->db->insert_id().

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Also, ignore the ArrayToDBString() methods, those are definitely not the issues since, like I said, I've printed the last query and ran it through SQL successfully. Also, the result I get when running it through SQL is a single column called ContactID.

Comment: How are you verifying that nothing is returned? This code, as is, won't have any output. If you're not sure if it's the query itself that's causing an issue, did you test with a simpler query? You seem to have several queries here, did you try them one at a time?

Comment: I'm echoing $result and it's showing nothing. I've also done a $this->db->last_query() to pull up the SQL and then ran it directly in Management Studio and verified it returns results there.

Comment: var_dump() it instead. If it is FALSE, echo won't show it. proceed one step at a time, first see if the code works, then see why there are no results

Comment: As I mentioned in the below answer, I tried print_r() as well and just got an empty array back.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm echoing `$result` and it's showing nothing

`row()` returns an object, not a string, even though you have selected only one column. To access the value, you still have to call it explicitly:

```
$record = $query->row();
echo $record->ContactID;
```

If that still doesn't work, try running your queries one at a time instead of passing all of them to `$this->db->query()` at once.

...and as always, turn error reporting on with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and use something like `var_dump()` or `print_r()` to debug variables, instead of `echo`.

Comment: Should have been a bit more clear. I tried print_r() as well and it just showed an empty array.

Comment: That's strange, it should at the least be an object, not an array. Are you sure you're using `row()`? What about running the queries separately, what happened? What happened when you tried another, simpler query, like `select * from tblCD`?

Comment: It may have been an object. I know at one point I also tried it with result and array_result so I could've been seeing the empty array from that which is why I mentioned it. Doing a simple query like a select works just fine. I'm using them all over the place, no problem. I'm wondering if $query() just doesn't like to return results from more complicated queries or something.

Comment: That''s why I keep suggesting that you try splitting this into multiple `query()` calls. Am I mistaken, and this is actually a single query and not 5 queries? It could very well be CI's "fault" for not returning anything after the first query completes (not sure). Do we know if any part of the query is even being run?

Comment: Both inserts run. The query just doesn't return my select. Won't my temp table go out of scope if I split it up into two queries? (Forgive me for not knowing, I don't use temp tables all that often.)

Comment: I'm not sure, this SQL is over my head. Doesn't hurt to try though.